# How do I implement a linked list with multi-element struct?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, linked-list

After several hours of reading, I think I can clarify my question. This is an assignment-related question but I am looking for help on a concept; not a solution to my exact code. My code is included for visualization purposes.

I have the following data in a text file that is read into my program:

```
HIS1043.002 MH2.102   MWF   1:00-1:50pm     120 35.00
GEO1013.005 MB1.101   TR   12:30-1:45pm       5 35.00
MAT1214.003 MS1.02.03 TR    2:00-3:15pm       1 35.00
CS1713.002  NPB1.202  MWF   1:00-1:50pm       0 50.00
MAT3013.001 MS1.02.07 TR    2:00-3:15pm       1 35.00
ENG1023.001 MH2.202   MWF  10:00-10:50am     15 35.00
```

And here are the two typedef structs I am using:

```
// Course Definition
typedef struct
{
    StudentNode *pWaitlistHead;    
    char szCourseId[12];  
    char szRoom[15];
    char szDays[15];
    char szTimes[15];  
    int  iAvailSeats; 
    double dFee; 
} Course;


// Node for course list
typedef struct CourseNode {
    struct CourseNode* pNext;
    Course course;
} CourseNode;
```

Here is the function that reads in the data from the file. Within the function, I call two other functions: one to allocate space for the course node and one to add the data to the list.

```
int getCourses(Course courseM[])
{
    char szInputBuffer2[100];
    int i = 0;

    while(fgets(szInputBuffer2, 100, pFileCourses) != NULL)
    {
        sscanf(szInputBuffer2, "%12s  %15s %8s %15s %d %lf", 
                          courseM[i].szCourseId, courseM[i].szRoom, 
                          courseM[i].szDays, courseM[i].szTimes, 
                          &courseM[i].iAvailSeats, &courseM[i].dFee);
    }
    //allocate space for linked-list
    pNew = allocateNodeC(courseM); //???

    //add courses to linked list
    insertN2CourseList(&pHead, &pNew);  

    return i;
}
```

My question is concerning how to handle the course description data in the list implementation. Do I need to address each element individually in the allocation? What about when reading in all the data from the file?

```
    //allocate space for CourseNode linked list
CourseNode *allocateNodeC(Course courseM[])
{
    CourseNode *pNew = malloc(sizeof(CourseNode));
    pNew->pNext = NULL;
    pNew->course.szCourseId = courseM[i].szCourseId; //?????
    pNew->course.szRoom = courseM[i].szRoom; //?????
    pNew->course.szDays = courseM[i].szDays; //?????
    pNew->course.szTimes = courseM[i].szTimes; //?????
    pNew->course.iAvailSeats = courseM[i].iAvailSeats; //?????
    pNew->course.dFee = courseM[i].dFee; //?????
    return pNew;
}
//add courses to linked list
CourseNode insertN2CourseList(CourseNode **ppHead, CourseNode *ppNew)
{
    CourseNode p*;
    if(*ppHead == NULL)
    {
        *ppHead = pNew;
        return;
    }
    for(p = *ppHead; p->pNext != NULL; p = p->pNext);
}
```

Comment: It appears that you are asking how to _implement a linked list_ rather that how to _"add data from an array to a list"_.  A list is not a thing in C or provided by the standard library, so how you add items to a list depends entirely on your list implementation.  Since it seems you have not yet written a list implementation, you are asking the wrong question perhaps.

Comment: I am working with linked lists and updating an existing program so I only included a portion of the code for the specific area I'm stuck on (also the starting point for the update). After reading in the course data, I now need to add it to a linked list but I don't really understand how that works with the array.

Comment: Good clarification, but it is now apparent that you have overcomplicated your question.  Your problem appears simply a matter of how to copy strings.  In C strings and arrays are not first class data types, and cannot be assigned using the = operator.

Comment: allocateNodeC should take a single Course object pointer, not the whole array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I needed to do to allocate memory for the linked course list:

```
CourseNode *allocateNode(Course course, CourseNode *pNext)
{
    CourseNode *pNew = malloc(sizeof(CourseNode));
    pNew->course = course;
    pNew->pNext = NULL;
}
```

And this is how I added the data from the array into the linked list:

```
void insertIntoList(CourseNode **ppHead, CourseNode *pNew)
{
    CourseNode *p;
    if(*ppHead == NULL) {
        *ppHead = pNew
        return;
    }

    for(p = *ppHead; p->pNext != NULL; p = p->pNext){
        //do nothing
    }
    p->pNext = pNew;
}
```

The calls for each function were placed inside of a loop that increased after each course description had been read into the program and then inserted into/add to the linked list before going to the next course description.

Answer (score 1):

`szCourseId`, `szRoom`, `szDays` and `szTimes` are of type `char []` which is used to store string read from file:

```
        sscanf(szInputBuffer2, "%12s  %15s %8s %15s %d %lf", 
                      courseM[i].szCourseId, courseM[i].szRoom, 
                      courseM[i].szDays, courseM[i].szTimes, 
                      &courseM[i].iAvailSeats, &courseM[i].dFee);
```

and in the `allocateNodeC()`, you are trying to assign to array:

```
    pNew->course.szCourseId = courseM[i].szCourseId; //?????
    pNew->course.szRoom = courseM[i].szRoom; //?????
    pNew->course.szDays = courseM[i].szDays; //?????
    pNew->course.szTimes = courseM[i].szTimes; //?????
```

In `C`, arrays are not assignable. Instead, you should copy the content of members of `courseM` to the new created node using `strcpy()`, like this:

```
    strcpy (pNew->course.szCourseId, courseM[i].szCourseId);
    strcpy (pNew->course.szRoom, courseM[i].szRoom);
    strcpy (pNew->course.szDays, courseM[i].szDays);
    strcpy (pNew->course.szTimes, courseM[i].szTimes);
```

Also, this doesn't seem to be actual code because in the function `allocateNodeC()` there is no declaration if `i` and you are accessing `courseM[i]`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. It is actual code but it is in the process of being updated and is imperfect at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

This is a single linked list -- i.e. a list that only points in one direction (next) instead of both directions (next, previous).

Using `-->` to indicate pointers, and `[...|next]` to indicate an item in the list...

For the empty case, you have:

```
head --> NULL
```

After adding a single item, you have:

```
head --> [1|next] --> NULL
```

After adding the second item, you can have either:

```
head --> [2|next] --> [1|next] --> NULL
```

or:

```
head --> [1|next] --> [2|next] --> NULL
```

depending on whether you iterated to the end of the list (the second example), or just updated from the head pointer (the first example). Adding other items work in the same way as adding the second item.